# Split durations defined by start and end timestamp on the hour

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, timestamp

I have a dataframe of Start and End timestamps like this:

```
              Start               End
0  2019-01-01 00:59  2019-01-01 01:01
1  2019-01-01 01:10  2019-01-01 03:10
```

And I want to split the durations on the hour (that is if a duration starts at 18:59 and ends at 19:05 we will have two new rows, one starting at 18:59 and ending at 19:00 and another starting at 19:00 and ending at 19:05). The output for my example dataframe would be:

```
              Start               End
0  2019-01-01 00:59  2019-01-01 01:00
1  2019-01-01 01:00  2019-01-01 01:01
2  2019-01-01 01:10  2019-01-01 02:00
3  2019-01-01 02:00  2019-01-01 03:00
4  2019-01-01 03:00  2019-01-01 03:10
```

I've tried a few things using the dt.ceil and dt.floor methods to figure out whether I need to break a line or not but I can't figure out a smooth way to do the whole transformation without looping through row by row.

Dataframes can be produced with the following snippets:

```
start = pd.DataFrame({
    'Start': ['2019-01-01 00:59', '2019-01-01 01:10'],
    'End': ['2019-01-01 01:01', '2019-01-01 03:10']
})

finish = pd.DataFrame({
    'Start': ['2019-01-01 00:59', '2019-01-01 01:00', '2019-01-01 01:10', '2019-01-01 02:00', '2019-01-01 03:00'],
    'End': ['2019-01-01 01:00', '2019-01-01 01:01', '2019-01-01 02:00', '2019-01-01 03:00', '2019-01-01 03:10']
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use listcomp, `pd.date_range` and construct series `s` from result of `date_range`. Finally, construct final `df` from `s`

```
a = [pd.date_range(s.ceil('H'), e, freq='H').insert(0,s) for s, e in zip(df.Start, df.End)]
s = pd.Series(a, index=df.index).explode()

df_final = (pd.DataFrame({'Start': s, 'End': s.groupby(level=0).shift(-1).fillna(df.End)})
              .reset_index(drop=True))

Out[41]:
                Start                 End
0 2019-01-01 00:59:00 2019-01-01 01:00:00
1 2019-01-01 01:00:00 2019-01-01 01:01:00
2 2019-01-01 01:10:00 2019-01-01 02:00:00
3 2019-01-01 02:00:00 2019-01-01 03:00:00
4 2019-01-01 03:00:00 2019-01-01 03:10:00
```

---

If you want output `Start` and `End` in string format, just add `strftime`

```
df_final = pd.DataFrame({'Start': s.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'), 
                         'End': s.groupby(level=0).shift(-1).fillna(df.End).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')})

Out[40]:
              Start               End
0  2019-01-01 00:59  2019-01-01 01:00
0  2019-01-01 01:00  2019-01-01 01:01
1  2019-01-01 01:10  2019-01-01 02:00
1  2019-01-01 02:00  2019-01-01 03:00
1  2019-01-01 03:00  2019-01-01 03:10
```

---

Note: if your pandas version doesn't support `explode`, you may use `df.index.repeat` and `np.concatenate` to create `s`

```
s = pd.Series(np.concatenate(a), index=df.index.repeat(list(map(len, a))))
```